# What's the appropriate way to upgrade Apache in RHEL?

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, redhat, rhel5

The version of Apache shipped in RHEL 5.4 is very old. A [feature I need](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbindauthoritative) only shipped recently. It seems Apache upstream only ships tarballs, and omits binary packages. Obviously I could build from source, but what's the canonical way to upgrade a single package like this?

Is it common procedure to drop a newer tarball in the existing SPEC, or does someone already do all this with an eye towards RHEL?

Answer (score 2):

When I supported a RHEL ES environment and wanted to upgrade a public domain software project....I'd download the latest Redhat Source RPM for the project, install the source RPM, and the new tarball for the new and improved software item.  Then I'd go through and adjust the spec file, the patches referenced by the spec file, and sometimes have to adjust the tarball itself.  Once you could make successfully make a package, I used rpm and installed the newly assembled binary package.

What this does is to ensure that the results of installing the package should be in the same locations as the package you are replacing.  Thus assuring some level of inter-operability and RedHat consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is not available via yum repositories.

If not may be there are some alternate repositories that have the version of apache you need. And the last resort recompile it/ However I do not recommend to use an apache from other source than RedHat as you will loose the support from RedHat.

Answer (score -1):

if your using from rhn.redhat.com you'll get old version you can use dag repo or centos repo and then yum install httpd* ldap* it will upgrade to new version !!!